# Proof the change of variables theorem by volume comparison

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

My books prove the change of variables theorem by admitting a lemma (it says that linear algebra is needed so the proof won't be listed in the book):

Let $\Psi:O\to \mathbb R$ be a smooth change of variable on the open subset $O$ of $\mathbb R^n$ (which means $\Psi$ is one-one and $D\Psi$ is invertible in $O$). Let $K$ be a closed bounded subset of $O$ and let $\epsilon>0$. Then there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $\mathbf J$ is any generalized rectangle of diameter less than $\delta$ and $\mathbf x$ is a point in $K\cap \mathbf J$, then $\mathbf J$ is contained in $O$ and

$$\text{Vol }\Psi(\mathbf J)=|\det D\Psi(\mathbf x)|\text{Vol }\mathbf J+E\text{ Vol }\mathbf J\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{where }|E|<\epsilon$$

I wonder how to proof it since I cannot find any proof on internet (most are weaker versions)

Comment: Could you disclose the name of the book and the page number?

Comment: @rych:Advanced calculas by Fitzpatrick p.511

Answer (score 0):

$D\Psi$ is the differential or linearization of the map $\Psi$, and let's denote it $A=D\Psi$. An infinitesimal parallelepiped formed by the vectors $(j_1,...j_n)\mapsto(Aj_1,...Aj_n)$, or, $J\mapsto AJ$ plus terms $H\propto \lVert J\rVert^2$. The geometric meaning of the determinant is that $|\det J|$ is the volume of the parallelepiped. $\det$ being a continuous map, the difference between $\det(AJ+H)$ and $\det(AJ)$ is of the same order as $H$. Finally, $\det (AJ)=\det A \det J$ and the result follows.